# Type "number" is not assignable to type void | Destructor

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have these 2 components:

DraggableGameStart

```
import DraggableGameAnswers from './DraggableGameAnswers';
import { useRef } from 'react';

function DraggableGameStart() {
    const draggableGame = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    return (
        <div className="draggable-game-content">
            <div className="draggable-game" ref={draggableGame}>
                    <DraggableGameAnswers elementBounds={draggableGame}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default DraggableGameStart;
```

and
DraggableGameAnswers

```
import { RefObject } from 'react';
import { useEffect } from 'react';

type DraggableGameAnswersProps = {
    elementBounds: RefObject<HTMLDivElement>
}

function DraggableGameAnswers(props: DraggableGameAnswersProps) {
    let boundsArray: Array<number>[];
    useEffect(
        () => 
        boundsArray.push(props.elementBounds.current?.getBoundingClientRect().top)
    )  
    
    return (
        <div className="draggable-game-answers">
            test
        </div>
    );
}

export default DraggableGameAnswers;
```

but I get some errors:

```
Type number is not assignable to type 'void | Destructor' ;
Argument of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number[]'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number[]'.
```

and I can't really understand why.

Why are those errors being thrown and how can I fix them?

Edit:

I changed to this line according to a comment

```
let boundsArray: Array<number>;
```

and nothing changed just the second error changed to this:

```
Argument of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Comment: is `boundsArray` really supposed to be an array of arrays? `Array<number>[]` is another way of writing `number[][]`... [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) takes a function that returns `void` or a destructor function, `push` returns the new length of the array.

Comment: @HereticMonkey no, it isn't, sorry for that. Modifying it with "let boundsArray: Array<number>;" throws nearly the same errors.

Comment: That makes sense, @HereticMonkey. Octavian, your `useEffect` function body is calling `.push(...top)`, and `Array.push` returns the count of objects in the array. You can probably just make the lambda a full function with braces and return nothing. `useEffect() => { /* existing push logic*/ }`. Using the braces gets rid of the implicit return.

Comment: @ps2goat it still doesn't work :(

Comment: @ps2goat if I change elementBounds to "any" from RefObject it will work, but I have no idea why.

Comment: You're also missing a closing div in `DraggableGameStart`. Notice in the code snippet above that there's an uncolored `</div>`-- you need another `</div>` there (I have the dark theme on). That plus the type change to not be an array of arrays (jagged array), plus the braces fixed the type checking for me.

Answer (score 0):

This error is important for you to read ad understand.

```
Argument of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

You'll notice that this value:

```
props.elementBounds.current?.getBoundingClientRect().top
```

Will not always be a number. If the `current` property is `undefined` then you get `undefined` instead. That's why this value has a type of `number | undefined`.

And you are pushing that to a an array of `number`s, which will not accept `undefined`, so you get this error.

To fix it, you simply have to check if the value is not `null` or `undefined` before pushing it to the array.

```
    let boundsArray: Array<number>;
    useEffect(() => {
      const value = props.elementBounds.current?.getBoundingClientRect().top
      if (value != null) {
        boundsArray.push(value) // works
      }
    })
```

[Working example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=9&pln=9&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDeikBmA8gEYBWSGcAvnAVBCHAORSobMDcAsAFCiRYuOAFcAzkgCiBApXi16jFm3QwufPjACeYJHAAiUFAHNjKEgBskAcRQgkAQQB2YgO5IoYgAoMwYuAC8uHxwoXBIVvZOMABCECJOACZiAFz4xORyADwAEgAqALIAMvrAAG6SkUjRAHx81Bq8BAkYwBBOBkam5la29s5uHmIAFGC+qZ0mZpY2do4u7p4+EH4AlMG8YXBW8CTxSWIOUEZaaUcnWU4iICQeNTybYeJSMnLDw+sBNRtboWjtYngZRQFhEeiCYxWYgAdBEkFFYvtktC0CJjtUYAB+aHGJCIhKJYBOYwAYQswAxyAwH2hMBWIV+wAIcGGwNBegAhEErhYLOscAzfnA9gTDscUFpoWBxAALVkgsHrAD0SrgrmgAGsxIKwg1HqFqOs4DqdWwYGiOsMdVssoSynA0BYUGIxAA5OYBABEiS60ysAFozPZ-SgFkNPXV9UKwjAkIDrWEskq7ZGtqsHnq+AJoPA8M9kMyFAwmKx2GoHnxmk5Wu1Jt0Zn0kABlGAoWAfH5hf4ueA+qY9Wb2QKiCQF3KFErlSrwjE1YY8vkVqNmi0shOhW3lB1Ol3u+xevv1gNBpD+7ux6IR9e-Tf2x3Ot0e72+geBuaeuBsAgBHCHv2DpBqFTaMQKyQx+wbOYBkWfw4QROJRR-P8B0baglWAkCN2TcoMJvbCylw9N6iAA)

Answer (score -1):

That error usually means you're passing a prop that doesn't fit the typescript interface you've defined for the component. I think what you're looking for in this case is forwarded refs, instead of passing a ref as a normal prop. It might look something like:

```
import { React, useEffect } from 'react';

const DraggableGameAnswers = React.forwardRef((props, ref) {
    let boundsArray: Array<number>[];
    useEffect(
        () => 
        boundsArray.push(ref.current?.getBoundingClientRect().top)
    )  
    
    return (
        <div className="draggable-game-answers">
            test
        </div>
    );
})

export default DraggableGameAnswers;
```

and then calling it like `<DraggableGameAnswers ref={draggableGame}/>` might at least point you in a different direction, if it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: You'll still have the same error because `useEffect` takes a function that returns `void | Destructor`, not `number`, as `push` returns.